# Session don't return any value after button is pressed

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, row

I have this script where I want to get a username from MySql server. I have a table with multiple users named "tb_user". Based on the user logged in I want to get his username using $_SESSION["id"]. Here is the code:

```
if(isset($_POST['sndmesaj'])){

        $id2= $_SESSION["id"];
        $connDB=mysqli_select_db($conn,'reglog');
        $result= mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tb_user WHERE id= $id2");
        $expeditor = $row['username'];

        echo
            "<script> alert('$expeditor'); </script>";
    
    }
```

I type it this way to be more specific about my problem, in the actual application I used parameterized prepared statements. The problem is that I don't get any value. I try the same way on another script and this works just fine. I checked the database connection, the ID that I get from $SESSION, even try the same query in SQL server which return the right result. Instead in my script I got the following warning:

```
Warning: Undefined variable $row in D:\XAMP\htdocs\pf\chatREMAKE.php on line 19
```

Here is how my table looks like:
[image: Table]

Comment: `$row` is used by not defined anywhere.

Comment: where is `mysqli_fetch_array` ?? you missed this line `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)` even your code is open for SQL injection use OOP

Comment: @devpro that was the problem, the $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) was missing. I know about that problem, this was a more simple way to ilustrate my problem. Thank you for your time guys.

Answer (score -1):

I forgot to define $row by $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) that was the reason that my result was empty in this script. Also if you find this useful, this exactly code is not secure so be careful about SQL Injection. This was only a simple way to show my problem. Use only parameterized prepared statements.

```
if(isset($_POST['sndmesaj'])){

        $id2= $_SESSION["id"];
        $connDB=mysqli_select_db($conn,'reglog');
        $result= mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tb_user WHERE id= $id2");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $expeditor = $row['username'];

        echo
            "<script> alert('$expeditor'); </script>";
    
    }
```

Comment: finally you find a solution but this code will give you error again :) like `missing ;`